# Bower packages install error

Tags: git, github, bower, command-prompt

I have installed bower in my project through npm.
Later I tried installing angular js through bower.

```
bower install angular#1.4.8
```

But I was getting the following error

```
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.8
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.8
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github
.com/angular/bower-angular.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to connect to g
ithub.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=No error

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=No error
```

I have read that these kind of errors occur due to firewall issue and git outdated issues?

But I tried,wasn't working for me unfortunately.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you behind proxy?

Comment: Check your internet proxy settings

Answer (score 0):

Your probably behind a firewall or a proxy, Thats whats causing the problem. Mostly likely to occur when your in an office network:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

If the problem persists,its a proxy server issue. Try this:

```
{
   "directory": "app/bower_components",
   "proxy": "http://proxyserver:port",
   "https-proxy": "http://proxyserver:port,
   "strict-ssl": false
}
```

and

```
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port
```